# Python Django website not recognizing css changes

Tags: python, html, css, django

I am making a django website and I am loading in my css and the html as static.

I am using two css files: the first is for the bootstrap that I am using, and the second is my own css.
However, the bootstrap variables are shown, but my own variables are not.

I have tried remaking the css document and changing from "class" to "id"

html code:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Wedding planner - Dashboard</title>
    <link href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap-4.3.1.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    {% block content %}
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'Home' %}">Wedding Planer</a>
      <button
        class="navbar-toggler"
        type="button"
        data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-expanded="false"
        aria-label="Toggle navigation"
      >
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"
              >Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a
            >
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Plans</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <a
          class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
          href="#"
          id="navbarDropdown"
          role="button"
          data-toggle="dropdown"
          aria-haspopup="true"
          aria-expanded="false"
        >
          User
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          {% if user.is_authenticated%}
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
          {% else %}
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="login">Login</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="register">Register</a>
          {% endif %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid text-center">
      <h1 class="display-4">Welcome, {{ user.username }}</h1>
      <p class="lead">
        {{ user.username }} this is the page where you can control all your
        wedding planing
      </p>
    </div>

    <div id="sidemenu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Guest</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shop list</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">lorem</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">lorem</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">lorem</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- <div class="bg-light border-right" id="sidebar-wrapper">
      <div class="sidebar-heading">Start Bootstrap</div>
      <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light"
          >Dashboard</a
        >
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light"
          >Shortcuts</a
        >
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light"
          >Overview</a
        >
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light"
          >Events</a
        >
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light"
          >Profile</a
        >
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light"
          >Status</a
        >
      </div>
    </div> -->

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js' %}"></script>

    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="{% static 'js/popper.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap-4.3.1.js' %}"></script>
    {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

css code:

```
.inthemiddle {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 100px;
}
.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
}
.Register {
  align-content: center;
  padding-top: 100px;
}
#sidemenu ul {
  padding-left: 50px;
  background-color: #c7c8d4;
}
#sidemenu li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
a {
  color: black;
}
#sidebar-wrapper {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin-left: -15rem;
  -webkit-transition: margin 0.25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: margin 0.25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: margin 0.25s ease-out;
  transition: margin 0.25s ease-out;
}

#sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-heading {
  padding: 0.875rem 1.25rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

#sidebar-wrapper .list-group {
  width: 15rem;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
  min-width: 100vw;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
  margin-left: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #sidebar-wrapper {
    margin-left: 0;
  }

  #page-content-wrapper {
    min-width: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }

  #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    margin-left: -15rem;
  }
}
```

What I am trying to do is to change the list to have a background color and remove the dots before the list but it is still showing and nothing is changing

Comment: Check in your browser dev tools if there are any errors, e.g. 404 not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your browser had cached assets. Try incognito/private browsing mode and if it runs. Press `ctrl + shift + r` in the page where the code above is loaded already.

Answer (score 3):

- Clear the browser cache or clear the complete history
- Press F12 Click on the Console
- See if there are 404 Errors or file not found error

[image]